# react, typescript - a type for both stateless and normal components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to implement a `ProtectedRoute` component that has a `component` prop - which can be a stateless (pure) component or a normal react component.

These are my types:

```
export interface Props {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  component: React.PureComponent | React.Component;
  exact?: boolean;
  path: string;
}
```

This is my ProtectedRoute component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { ROUTES } from '../../constants/routes';

import { Props } from './ProtectedRoute.types';

const ProtectedRoute = (props: Props) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, component: Component, ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      children={props =>
        !isAuthenticated ? (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: ROUTES.login, state: { from: props.location } }} />
        ) : (
          <Component {...props} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

I am getting the following error here:

> Type error: JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct
>   or call signatures.  TS2604

This is how I use it:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import ProtectedRoute from './ProtectedRoute';

import { ROUTES } from '../../constants/routes';

import Login from '../Login/Login';
const PlaceholderComponent = () => <div>This is where we will put content.</div>;
const NotFoundPlaceholder = () => <div>404 - Route not found.</div>;

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={ROUTES.login} component={Login} />
      {/* TODO protected route */}
      <ProtectedRoute exact path={ROUTES.list} component={PlaceholderComponent} />
      <ProtectedRoute exact path={ROUTES.procedure} component={PlaceholderComponent} />
      {/* catchall route for 404 */}
      <Route component={NotFoundPlaceholder} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

And getting the following error here:

> Type '() => Element' is not assignable to type 'PureComponent<{}, {},
>   any> | Component<{}, {}, any>'.   Type '() => Element' is missing the
>   following properties from type 'Component<{}, {}, any>': context,
>   setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more. [2322]

This makes me think that I am using the incorrect type definition. What would be the 'correct' way to go about this? My purpose is to check that `ProtectedRoute` always gets a React component as the `component` prop.

Comment: how typescript tag linked to the react subject? it makes no sense

Comment: it is a typescript error coming from a typescript file, regarding type definitions?

Comment: "TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript created by Microsoft" - that tag is used  for typescript syntax, as i know, but in your case the error firied in a library or package you use. I think it's better to specify lib's/package's tag instead of typescript. is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type for both functional and class components is `ComponentType`.

It should be:

```
export interface Props {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  component: React.ComponentType;
  exact?: boolean;
  path: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably found it, but will leave this open, since I do not know if this is the correct solution:

```
export interface Props {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  component: React.ComponentClass<any> | React.StatelessComponent<any>;
  exact?: boolean;
  path: string;
}
```